# Sentry.io Performance Monitoring doesn't work | Ruby

Tags: ruby, sentry

I'm using sentry.io performance monitoring feature but it doesn't work.
I've sent the error log successfully, It appeared in issues but not in performance feature

[issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlukG.png)

[performances](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trVVK.png)

sentry config :

```
Sentry.init do |config|
  config.dsn = <my dsn>
  config.environment = "development"


  config.traces_sampler = lambda do |context|
    true
  end

  config.backtrace_cleanup_callback = lambda do |backtrace|
    nil
  end

end
```

please help

Answer (score 0):

You could verify by setting `traces_sample_rate = 1.0`, and remove `config.traces_sampler` setting for now.

[Set Up Performance](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/ruby/guides/rails/performance/)

> Verify that performance monitoring is working correctly by setting traces_sample_rate to 1.0 as that ensures that every transaction will be sent to Sentry.